# Helpp for install cstore_fdw

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

I'm actually trying to install sctore_fdw but I just have a little question for the installation.

I follow a tutorial and it is asking to do this :

> you need to include the pg_config directory path in your make command

This is my pg_config path:

```
/usr/bin/pg_config
```

I have some difficulty with Linux and specifically with the make command, so what i'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this like the instructions specify (ref: https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw)?

```
PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH make
sudo PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH make install
```

Comment: yes I already tried it, I had this answer : `make *** no targets specified and no makefile found. stop` when i trying the first command

Comment: Are you in the same directory as the unpacked source?  According to that output the makefile can't be found.  Can you post the directory listing to a gist?

Comment: oh my god thank you, I wasn't in the good directory. Now that works. Thank you !

Comment: no prob can you please mark it as the answer so i get the points? 